# Is there any way i need to protect from url injection?

Tags: php, api

I need to connect to API of specific company, they offer a simple api which you can get data by simple url.
for example: https://example.com?user=xxx&pass=xxx&data=specificdata

My question is:

I have a function which get parameters and connect to api:

```
public function urlRequest($base_url, $company_id, $user_name, $password, $parameters) {
    if (isset($base_url) && isset($company_id) && isset($user_name) && isset($password) && count($parameters) > 0) {
        $url = "https://$base_url?compID=$company_id&user=$user_name&pass=$password&$parameters";
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

1.Is there any way i need to protect from url injection and if so, which functions can be relevant for it? (htmlentities, etc...)

2.Which characters can not be in url and i need to protect from, is this similar to sql injection?

Comment: its not your api, there's nothing you need to do to the variables passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is appropriate to protect the url , if there cursiosas people and change the id of the url , they might see data from other users.

It could protect it with the md5 function PHP, i leave a little example.

```
<?php

//Put it on a directoria safty and include it to get value.
$clave = "4V}ee[TL&]=cA;kv-SYVg&vVKz!teJ_PW93G*u>F6z[R)]-TMeW.{~Q&Ee(qyag?_KC@]&=_sc1(jkc7p~b-d)|tNV^qR}Q^>@2";

//Set safety, for URL.
$company_id = $ConDB->real_escape_string($row['company_id']);               

//Protect 'URL' for our page.
$protectid = md5($clave.$company_id);

//Your function.
public function urlRequest($base_url, $company_id, $user_name, $password, $parameters) {
    if (isset($base_url) && isset($company_id) && isset($user_name) && isset($password) && count($parameters) > 0) {
        $url = "https://$base_url?compID=$protectid&user=$user_name&pass=$password&$parameters";
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        return $response;
    }
}



//To see return the outcome data, let we see how we can bring back our results with the md5 function (page: base_url)

$id = $_GET['compID'];//GET 'ID' 'URL' with protected.

//query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE md5(CONCAT('$clave', company_id)) = '$id'";
$resultado = $ConDB->query($sql);



?>
```